# All Input arrays must have the same shape in Python np.stack

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a nucleotide sequences and I am trying to convert them to an array. The below code works fine for a file which has 999 sequences and doesnot work for anything smaller or bigger than those.

Sample code is as follows

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
integer_encoder = LabelEncoder()  
one_hot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(categories='auto')   
input_features = []

for sequence in sequences:
  integer_encoded = integer_encoder.fit_transform(list(sequence))
  integer_encoded = np.array(integer_encoded).reshape(-1, 1)
  one_hot_encoded = one_hot_encoder.fit_transform(integer_encoded)
  input_features.append(one_hot_encoded.toarray())

np.set_printoptions(threshold=40)
input_features = np.stack(input_features, axis = -1)

ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape
```

Expected output is

```
DNA sequence 1#
AAGCGGGGGT.....GTGGTGTATA
one hot encoding of Sequence #1:

[[1.1.0.....1.0.1]
[0.0.0....0.0]]
```

Comment: What's the question?  Evidently one or more of the arrays in `input_features` has a different shape from the rest.  Only you can figure out which, and why.

Comment: There was one line that was of different shape, we removed it and tried but still same error

Comment: The only file that works is the one that has 999 sequences

Comment: I don't think the 999 is significant.